# set a fixed zoom for an imageoverlay in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm using an imageoverlay in leaflet

```
var imageUrl = 'img.png';
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl,mapBounds1).addTo(map);
```

When i zoom the map, the image zooms also , is there any way to make the image static ?

I also tried tiles (from the image), and it zooms also, i'm wondering if the only way is to create multiple tiles for each zoom.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
map.on('zoomstart', function(e) {
  //remove layer
});

map.on('zoomend', function(e) {
  //add layer back with new bounds
});
```

Comment: it's what i did. Thanks !!

Comment: Cool deal, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe somehow to the `viewreset` event

> `viewreset` is fired when the map needs to reposition its layers (e.g. on zoom), and latLngToLayerPoint is used to get coordinates for the layer's new position. (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-viewreset)

I'm not sure this will work, but try something like

```
var imageUrl = 'img.png';
var overlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl,mapBounds1).addTo(map);
overlay.off('viewreset');
```